# If mean is 0 can we say distribution is symmetric about 0

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $E(X)=0$ can we say that the distribution is symmetric about 0

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You can say it, but it won't necessarily be true.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is the converse is true? Normal distribution is symmetrical but $E(X) \ne 0 $

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following counterexample, for a random variable $X$ with a probability mass function $f$:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac12 & x=\frac32 \\ \frac14 & x=-1 \\ \frac14 & x=-2 \end{cases}$$

Then, $E(X)=0$, but the distribution is not symmetric about $0$.